# How to add NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons after all the items to list box in windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

In my windows phone 8 application I'm displaying the result in list box. Every time I'm showing  only 20 items in the list.

Now to show the next 20 items i want to add NEXT button and also to show the old items i want to add PREVIOUS buttons.

Below is my code block. In this i'm using the list box inside another list box to show the buttons after the list. But the list is not scrolling.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="3" Background="White" Margin="0,-3,0,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="outerList">
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="companiesList"  SelectionChanged="companiesList_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="listItem">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel x:Name="namePanel" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="50">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" MaxHeight="40" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="460" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <StackPanel x:Name="addressPanel" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="30">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="addressTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Address}" Foreground="#FF1F1F1F" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="460"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <StackPanel x:Name="phonePanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="30">
                                    <Image x:Name="phone" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="25" Source="Images/list_phone.png"  />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="phoneTextBlock" Text="{Binding Phone1}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Width="460"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <Image  x:Name="line" Grid.Row="3" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/separator.png"  />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="50" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Previous" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-5,1,0,0" Name="prevbutton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" Foreground="#FF501F6E">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/blank_button_nav.png"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <Button Content="Next" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,1,0,0" Name="nextbutton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" Foreground="#FF501F6E">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/blank_button_nav.png"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Could you please help me how to add buttons to the list box which is scrollable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put them outside of the listbox, so the user can tap them without having to scroll all the way down?

Comment: nope, user has to scroll all the items that is my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your ListBox inside another ListBox, where the items are the result ListBox and the buttons, e.g:

```xaml
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="3" Background="White" Margin="0,-3,0,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="outerList">
            <ListBox x:Name="companiesList" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ContentPanel}"  SelectionChanged="companiesList_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="listItem">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel x:Name="namePanel" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="50">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" MaxHeight="40" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="460" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel x:Name="addressPanel" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="30">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="addressTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Address}" Foreground="#FF1F1F1F" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="460"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel x:Name="phonePanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="30">
                                <Image x:Name="phone" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="25" Source="Images/list_phone.png"  />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="phoneTextBlock" Text="{Binding Phone1}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Width="460"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <Image  x:Name="line" Grid.Row="3" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/separator.png"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Height="50" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Previous" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-5,1,0,0" Name="prevbutton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" Foreground="#FF501F6E">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/blank_button_nav.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Next" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,1,0,0" Name="nextbutton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" Foreground="#FF501F6E">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/blank_button_nav.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

When buttons tapped, you could modify the content of the inner ListBox:

Comment: When I put the buttons as you said, then the list is not scrolling. How should we make the list scroll

Comment: Hi I need to show search results in list box with 20 items per page. At the bottom I've to show two buttons previous and next and buttons should be shown after 20th item only. And the list item should be clickable also. how can i achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. You can make the inner list scroll by binding its Height property to ContentsPanel's ActualHeight property. The problem is that then it wouldn't scroll to the buttons.

Comment: I put the listbox in another list box but Buttons are not displaying. What is the problem?